# Good Form in Launching a Parallel.ForEach in a New Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

I am working on a Windows service project. The service starts an engine. The engine has one to many "pollers" that I want to each run in its own thread so that they will do their "polling" in parallel. I am using Parallel.ForEach in the engine's Start() method to get the pollers polling and that's working great. I'd like the service to be able to start the engine, however, and then go on to do other things (like report on the status of the engine and it's pollers at various points or whatever). Is this the best way to start the engine without the primary thread being blocked:

```
    System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker worker = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
worker.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler((sender, e) => Parallel.ForEach(Pollers.Where(p => p.Active), p => p.StartPolling()));
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Or does anyone have any ideas on a better way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd go with the .Net 4 Task Library, much much cleaner than the old Thread model

```
// Create a task and supply a user delegate by using a lambda expression.
var taskA = new Task(() =>Parallel.ForEach(Pollers.Where(p => p.Active), p =>p.StartPolling()));

// Start the task.
taskA.Start();
```

you can Read more about the [Task Parallel Library HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx)

EDIT: You need to include this namespace:  `System.Threading.Tasks`

EDIT2: Yes, as commented it would probably be better if you use the

`Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>{ Parallel.ForEach(Pollers.Where(p => p.Active);})`

however you should be aware that it is NOT always the best way, depending on the code, check out  [THIS MSDN BLOG](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/06/13/10024153.aspx) to read more about the difference between the two

Comment: This would be my suggestion, except that I'd recommend using `Task.Factory.StartNew( () => ...` as opposed to manually creating and starting the task.  This is the suggested API for "launching" a hot task (at least until Task.Run is added in vNext).

Comment: I'll give that a try. Thanks for the quick response. I tried that essentially... actually I used the Task.Factory.StartNew which I believe would be the same thing and it seemed to have some issues. I think some of the threads randomly decided to freeze or stop. Do I need to somehow mark the tasks as "LongRunning" like I had to once before?

Comment: You shouldnt need to, although the task will only live for a little bit, it will go through all the pollers, start a new thread for each (actually not one for each, but just think so that way for now) and as soon as it finishes going through the Parallel.Foreach there the function will be over so the Task will end. The pollers however will keep polling, I guess you have an endless loop inside StartPolling or so

Comment: Yeah, basically an endless loop inside StartPolling(). Thanks guys. I'll read the MSDN article and try Task.Factory.StartNew() again.

Answer (score -1):

I would prefer using Thread, rather than BackgroundWorker.

Comment: You could be right but without an explanation it's hardly an answer.